# How to apply expander to ListViewItem?

Tags: wpf

Say I have the expander:(reference from [the article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248112/Templating-WPF-Expander-Control))

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleExpanderTemp" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
<DockPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton"

                  DockPanel.Dock="Top"

                  Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderButtonTemp}"

                  Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"

                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"

                  OverridesDefaultStyle="True"

                  Padding="1.5,0">
    </ToggleButton>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent"

                      Visibility="Collapsed"

                      DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
</DockPanel>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="ExpanderContent" 

          Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Now I want to use expander on ListViewItems.
The list view doesn't have the itemsSource. I use hard copy here.

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Top>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition />
             <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Expander Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderButtonTemp}" Grid.Row="0" />
        <ListViewItem Grid.Row="1>
            <StackPanel>
                 <Button Height="50"> Test</Botton>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
   </ListView>
```

My question is how to apply the expander to the list view item? I think in the template the ContentPresenter is a placeholeder, then I will replace the ListViewItem with it?

**EDIT**

I want something like

[image: demo]

Row 1 is a togglebutton.
Row 2 is a list view item.
Of course I have many list view items. Each one should have its expanders. In the image I only list one.

Comment: IIRC, the Expander works on its content. So I'd say <ListViewItem> <Expander> <StackPanel>...</StackPanel></Expander></ListViewItem>.

Comment: Do you want to display the ListViewItem in the Expander or what is your question?

Comment: @mm8, I added an image for demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `Content` of the `Expander` to whatever you want, for example a `ListViewItem`:

```
<Expander Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderButtonTemp}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListViewItem Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="50">Test</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</Expander>
```

It's the `Content` that is expanded and collapsed.

You don't need to explicitly create `ListViewItems` inside a `ListView` though so you probably just want to add the `StackPanel` to the `Expander`:

```
<Expander Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderButtonTemp}" Grid.Row="0">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="50">Test</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Should I put `Expander` inside `ListViewItem`?

Comment: No. There is a ListViewItem container created implicitly.

Comment: Actually it is not working in my case, but if I put the Expander inside ListViewItem then it works out.Because ListViewItem is an element of ListView. However in some cases your code is working, I still don't understand it.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.